# Sorting a multidimensional array when the numbers are strings in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, zend-framework

I'm creating a ticket system in Zend Framework and I need to sort the tickets by status, only problem is that the status is a string.

This is what one entry in my array looks like:

```
`[1] => array(14) {
    ["ticket_id"] => string(3) "147"
    ["created_at"] => string(19) "2017-02-23 14:21:55"
    ["updated_at"] => string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["deadline"] => string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["scheduled_for"] => string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["priority"] => string(1) "1"
    ["tracker"] => string(1) "1"
    ["status"] => string(1) "3"
    ["author"] => string(1) "12"
    ["assigned_group"] => string(0) ""
    ["uploadedFiles"] => string(0) ""
    ["uploadedFileName"] => string(0) ""
    ["title"] => string(19) "Sample problem"
  }`
```

Does anyone know how to sort this by status the status can be a number from 1 to 5

**Edit:** So far i've attempted these solutions

```
function natorder($a,$b) { 
   return strnatcmp ( $a['status'],  $b['status'] ); 
} 

uasort ($array, 'natorder');
```

from: http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10244548-natsort()-on-a-multidimensional-array

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
});
```

from: [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

I'm using php 7 if anyone is wondering.

Comment: Show us what attempts you have made so far.

Comment: try `usort($ar, function($a, $b) { return $a['status'] <=> $b['status'];})` and then output the `$array` [EDITED]

Comment: @HH That did the trick somehow. thanks a lot! I tried that one before but it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `usort($array, function($a, $b) { return $a['status'] <=> $b['status'];})`

tested using:

```
[
 [
   "name" => "a",
   "status" => "2",
 ],
 [
   "name" => "b",
   "status" => "4",
 ],
 [
   "name" => "c",
   "status" => "1",
 ],
 [
   "name" => "d",
   "status" => "3",
 ],
```

]

which outputs

```
[
 [
   "name" => "c",
   "status" => "1",
 ],
 [
   "name" => "a",
   "status" => "2",
 ],
 [
   "name" => "d",
   "status" => "3",
 ],
 [
   "name" => "b",
   "status" => "4",
 ],
```

]

after you run the

`usort($array, function($a, $b) { return $a['status'] <=> $b['status'];})`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function with the spaceshift operator:

```
$arr = [
    ['status' => '3'],
    ['status' => '2'],
    ['status' => '2'],
    ['status' => '1']
];

uasort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['status'] <=> $b['status'];
});

print_r($arr);
```

result ([sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/62926592ddcc59c6ce4675afe0388b9a4a9c2eff)):

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [status] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [status] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [status] => 2
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => 3
        )

)
```